# Instead of builder pattern involving a separate static class is it possible to just do it directly on the object itself, given the object is mutable?

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder

So the object I am trying to create can be mutable. Is it okay to do something like this:

```
GetUserTopicsQuery request = GetUserTopicsQuery.getInstance().setUserId(mUserId).setName("Bob");
```

where `setUserId` returns `GetUserTopicsQuery` after setting the field `userId` and `setName` sets the `name` field.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but this is no more a design pattern. The scope of the Builder design pattern it's to provide no access to the constructor. It's not a problem if you have access to getters and setters if you can't instantiate an object.

This is the reason that you need a nested class, because you don't want to provide access to the constructor, but to the build method instead.